# Filtering JavaRDD in three RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I want to filter a JavaRdd to three different RDDs based on a specific condition.Right now I am reading the same rdd thrice and filtering it.Is there any other efficient way to achieve this in single scan?

```
Example:

Like I have an rdd of type string and I want to filter it based on name 'anshu','suman' and 'neeraj'

rdd1=rdd.filter(s->{s.contains("anshu")?return true; else return false;})
rdd2=rdd.filter(s->{s.contains("suman")?return true; else return false;})
rdd3=rdd.filter(s->{s.contains("neeraj")?return true; else return false;})

Instead of filtering same rdd thrice,can I do it in single filter?
```

Comment: Can you provide your use case. That will help in answer. Like what is your input and what your are expecting.

Comment: @cody123-added the example

Comment: @cody123-thanks,this will give you a single rdd,but i want three different rdds of type anshu,suman and neeraj to perform some further operation on them.

Comment: You can further perform operation on resultant rdd on the basis of keys.

Comment: If i have to perform further operation on anshu,i dont have key now,can you give some sample example how to achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125271/discussion-between-cody123-and-yanky).

Comment: Done if you still have some queries we can discuss on chat.

Comment: thanks but my use case is bit different i want three rdd from a single rdd,can we discuss on chat if you wish?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with below example. Here I am using map where all your three condition will behave as key and we can use reduce to group values associated with those keys.

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> rdd = javaSparkContext.textFile("/tmp/mathsetdata.dat").filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
                String split[] = v1.split(" ");
                return split[0].equals("suman") || split[0].equals("anshu") || split[0].equals("neeraj");
            }
        }).mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, List<String>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, List<String>> call(String t) throws Exception {
                String split[] = t.split(" ");
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(split[1].trim());
                return new Tuple2<String, List<String>>(split[0].trim(), list);
            }
        }).reduceByKey(new Function2<List<String>, List<String>, List<String>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public List<String> call(List<String> v1, List<String> v2) throws Exception {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.addAll(v1);
                list.addAll(v2);
                return list;
            }
        }).values();
```

**Sample File :**

```
suman 1001
anshu 1002
neeraj 1003
suman 1006
anshu 1007
neeraj 1008
suman 1016
anshu 1027
neeraj 1018
```

Further operations can also be performed.for eg.

```
Tuple2<String, Integer> rdds = rdd.filter(new Function<Tuple2<String, List<String>>, Boolean>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, List<String>> v1) throws Exception {
                return v1._1.equals("suman");
            }
        }).map(new Function<Tuple2<String, List<String>>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<String, List<String>> v1) throws Exception {
                Integer sum = 0;
                for (String str : v1._2) {
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
                }
                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(v1._1, sum);
            }
        }).collect().get(0);
```